# modify linq to get first 5 elements

Tags: c#, linq

```
var lastArticles = from a in be.MyTable
                   where a.id == 1
                   join c in be.OtherTable on a.parent equals c.id
                   orderby a.timestamp descending
                   select new { a, cName = c.name};
```

I need to get the first 5 elements.

I'm doing it by

```
.Take(5)
```

but is there a way to do in in the linq statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you need to use [`Skip()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357513.aspx) and [`Take()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300906.aspx) as method calls. There is no LINQ-specific equivalent.

```
var lastArticles = (from a in be.MyTable
                    where a.id == 1
                    join c in be.OtherTable on a.parent equals c.id
                    orderby a.timestamp descending
                    select new { a, cName = c.name }).Take(5);
```

Comment: I dislike this because you are always forced to put `(...)` wrappers around your queries, and it conflagurates the distinction between a lazy enumerable query, and the results of running the query.  Most often in cases where I want to immeditaely run the query, I'll have it abstracted in a method call with two lines - 1 the query, 2 - `return query.someenumerationfunction()` instead.

Comment: @asawyer: `Take` is very much part of the query - there's nothing "eager" about Take.

Comment: This is exactly why I stopped writing LINQ and work straight with extension methods. You become fluent with the dot-notation really quickly.

Comment: @Yuck Yes I seem to need more coffee this morning. I meant "to confuse" not to lite on fire. Woops.

Comment: @asawyer I had the links pointing to `Enumerable` versions of `Skip()` and `Take()` but in the example above it does in fact use the `Queryable` implementations.

Answer (score 1):

A linq Query should always be separate from the products of running that query.

`.Take()` produces results, and thus should be separate and distinct from the query.

```
//data query
var lastArticlesQuery = from a in be.MyTable
                   where a.id == 1
                   join c in be.OtherTable on a.parent equals c.id
                   orderby a.timestamp descending
                   select new { a, cName = c.name};

//results of that query at this time
var lastArticles = lastArticlesQuery.Take(5);
```

Comment: @AdrianIftode Same idea for `Skip()`. And +1, this is a nice way of thinking about LINQ data access.

Comment: @AdrianIftode I don't see `.Skip()` mentioned in the question, but it is part of query enumeration, and should also be separate from the query itself.

Comment: @AdrianIftode Absolutely not. `Select` is a delegate that is run once per enumeration to transform it, or "Project" it into a different shape. It does not enumerate the query.

Comment: @aswayer: `Take` does not enumerate the query either. You may be confusing it with `ToList()` or `ToArray()` ?

Comment: It really depends on the context. If the Select is used over an IQueryable, then you're right in some way, since the delegate is not used to project a type into another type, but to know what columns to pick. But if the Select is used over an IEnumerable, then yes, it projects (it enumerates and projects). If it's IEnumerable, every extension uses an iterator, but if it's IQueryable, the behavior depends on the provider's implementation. With linq 2 sql Take method is not a "stop - until here is the query" method, but ToList and AsEnumerable are.

Comment: Or ToArray, as @BrokenGlass said (might be others :))

Comment: @AdrianIftode The context distinction is a good point, thank you. I think my overall point of keeping query/results separate still stands.

Answer (score 1):

This code is only syntatic sugar, utlimately it will be converted to a LINQ-methods chain that will look something like:

```
var lastArticles = be.MyTable
    .Where(a => a.id == 1)
    .Join(be.OtherTable, a => a.parent, c => c.id,
    (a, c) => new { a, c})
    .OrderByDescending(@t => @t.a.timestamp)
    .Select(@t => new { @t.a, cName = @t.c.name });
```

So having a keyword for `Take()` would only add to the sytactic sugar and it would need to be re-converted as well.

In short, no, the only way is to use the `Take()` method.

Comment: After switching from pure LINQ to extension methods, I find them more consistent and simpler to read.

Comment: Really? I personally find the query syntax much more readable for "complex" queries, such as this one.

Comment: Really. LINQ, just as SQL, is intended to be readable, but imho ends up providing really arbitrary syntax. Extension methods, on the other hand, operate in traditional C# bounds, which most developers enjoy.